# Preventing inline images from loading in emacs notmuch

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/) as my email client and using its default interface, the emacs mode. I'm trying to figure out how to prevent it from displaying images in email - since I'm using it for my professional email, the images are pretty much always unwelcome (I also am an enemy of those 1-pixel tracking tags that some anti-social services poke into HTML email).

I'm coming up empty on Google searches and consulting the notmuch mode documentation and <kbd>M-x customize</kbd> options. I assume, though, that there's some elisp value I can twiddle to make this work, and it's simply not obvious to me.

How can I tell notmuch to ignore images, or alternatively, to display only the text part of emails by default, ignoring MIME/HTML content?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to `~/.emacs` seemed to do it for me:

```
(gnus-inhibit-images t)
```

Comment: I've formatted your code, but I wasn't sure about the leading single quote. Please fix if it needs to be kept!

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I wouldn't have assumed that a `gnus-foo` option would work. I'll try that.